# Error can't read "filename" : no such variable

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am looking to create a function to add the recent opening files to menu and command (event) to open it when clicking, but an error appears

**Error :**

```
Error can't read "filename" : no such variable
```

**Code :**

```
proc add_Recentfiles {filename} {
 global recentFiles
 ...
 $m insert $recentFiles(index) \
       command -label $labelText -command {fileOpen $filename}
 ...
}

proc fileOpen { filename } {
    #refresh textbox
    .textarea.txt delete 0.0 end

    set fileid [open $filename r]
    set data [read $fileid]

    .textarea.txt insert end $data
    .textarea.l  configure -text $filename

    addRecentFile $filename 

    close $fileid

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're delaying evaluation on the variable too long.  Instead of

```
... - command {fileOpen $filename}
```

Try

```
... - command [list fileOpen $filename]
```

When you use `{braces}`, all variable substitution is suppressed, so the command becomes the literal string `fileOpen $filename` and then later you will try to open a file literally named "$filename".

Using `[list fileOpen $filename]`, you allow the variable to be expanded but also ensure that, even if the filename contains spaces, you are going to pass exactly one argument to the fileOpen proc.

Comment: thank you, can you explained why we need [list ..] to make it work ?

Comment: Um, not quite, right? The command is evaluated in global scope, so the problem in the first case is that there is no such global variable. If one existed, its value would be used. In the second case, the command invocation has already had the variable substituted, so it just gets executed as is in the global scope.